# nonlinear least square

Tags: matlab, numerical-optimization

After some reading of Numerical Optimization, I am looking for some practice. Is there any practical resources of these problems. I mean with specific MATLAB code

I've been looking but so far there are just theoretical texts and coding with MATLAB can barely be found

I'm focusing on some nonlinear methods like Gauss-Newton or Levenberge-Marquerdt

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by now

I have convinced myself that these sorts of problems have been well solved already. And therefore, those applications are not mentioned. Moreover, as I understand, these ones are quite primitively applicable. I mean, these methods restrict to local problems whereas concurrent studies are focusing on global problems with innovative strategies.

What I've found during the last investigation include some optimization packages of C++ and some functions of MATLAB e.g. fmincon, fsolve, solve, nonlinsq...